# Python3でOpenCVをMacで使用したい．

Tags: python, macos, opencv

タイトル通りPython3でOpenCVを使用したいです．
しかし，OpenCV3.0.0がすでにインストールされているのですが，
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/lib
の中には"Python2.7"のフォルダしかありません．

OpenCV3.0.0インストール時に"--with-Python3"をつけていなかったのだと思います．
今まではC++で使用していたので問題なく使用できているのですが，Python3で使用したときPathを通すべきフォルダがないので，困っています．
brew install opencv3 --with-python3
と新たに実行しようとしても，"OpenCV3 already installed"と怒られてしまいます．

どうすればよいでしょうか？
お力をお貸しいただければと思います．

Answer (score 2):

再インストールしましょう。

```
brew update
brew reinstall opencv3 --HEAD --with-python3
```

2016/10/18現在、macOS Sierraでは`--HEAD`なしではエラーになります。おそらくQTが引退になりAVFoundationに移行した関係。

Comment: 無事，インストールし直すことができました．